# Find if folder exists FROM GLOBAL PATH nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Really simple question. How do I check if a folder or file exists from a global path in nodejs. `fs.exists` and `fs.existsSync` are both relative, and will not resolve global paths. `fs.access` also does not work. These all look for files with the current directory appended to the beginning of the path, so

```
file:\C:\dev\JS\Node\Test\src

Resolves to 

file:\C:\dev\JS\Node\Test\C:\dev\JS\Node\Test\src
```

Currently I have tried:

```js
//node_modules/foo/foo.js
    export class foo{
        constructor(path){
            this.options = {srcDir: path};
        }
    }
    async load(){
        try{
            await fs.promises.access(this.options.srcDir);
        }catch{
            console.log(`${`ERROR!: Could not find source directory.`.red.bold} ${this.options.srcDir.cyan.italic} ${`was not found`.red.bold}`)
            return;
        }
        //...
    }

//index.js
import {foo} from 'foo';
new foo(__dirname + '/src').load();

// -> ERROR!: Could not find source directory...
```

And

```
...

load(){
    if(!fs.existsSync(this.options.srcDir)){
        console.log(`${`ERROR!: Could not find source directory.`.red.bold} ${this.options.srcDir.cyan.italic} ${`was not found`.red.bold}`)
        return;
    }
}
...
```

Both do not work. What is a solution that would resolve?

Answer (score 0):

The `fs` module supports both relative and absolute paths - from the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_paths):

> [...]String form paths are interpreted as UTF-8 character sequences
> identifying the absolute or relative filename.[...]

If you want to use backslashes you need to escape them using `\\` (alternatively use forward slashes and even better the `path`-module to normalize/resolve the path):

```
const fs = require('fs') (
async function load(){
    try{
       await fs.promises.access("D:\\development\\test.txt");
       console.log("Can access file");
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
}
(async () => {
    await load();
})();
```

Above code runs as expected in my windows-vm.